# C++ 11 - bind a C style callback to a class member function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

Using code from http://ideone.com/5MHVz
I am curious how is it possible that I can bind a lambda function (inline) to a C style function pointer but I cannot do this with a class function even if there is no state involved. It must be some fundamental difference but I don't understand how lambda binding is possible in this case then (there is a conceptual this to lambda generated code also). Is there a workaround ?

Code bellow:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

typedef int (*http_cb) (int*);

struct http_parser_settings {
  http_cb      on_message_begin;
};

class HttpParser
{
  int OnMessageBegin(int* val){}

  HttpParser()
  {
    http_parser_settings settings;
    //settings.on_message_begin = std::bind(&HttpParser::OnMessageBegin, this, std::placeholders::_1); -- this one does not compile
   settings.on_message_begin = [](int* p){ return 0;};
  }
};

int main() {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Non-capturing lambdas can be converted to function pointers. They're essentially free functions, so there's no problem.

Comment: As long as you are not using MSVC2010.

Comment: @Steve-o Yes, but they implemented the required functionality in VS11

Answer (score -1):

You can store lambdas in std::function objects even in MSVC2010, so there must be a way to get a raw function pointer.  I've never delved into the details of how it works, but have certainly used this feature before.

Comment: Why would you need a function pointer to store something in a `std::function`? There should really be no problem with storing functors in `std::function`

Comment: But a functor such as std::function is merely a wrapper around a function pointer.  Isn't it?

Comment: It really isn't. It's a wrapper around any kind of callable entity (which means function pointers or functor objects). And a Functor is a callable object which has really nothing to do with a function pointer (the most important differences being that it can have (non static) state and that the call to `operator()` can potentially be inlined).

Comment: @Grizzy, this is intriguing, if a little off-track!  I had assumed that if I declared say: std::function<void (const CRect &)>, then I was templating the std::function on a function-pointer type, and it would store a pointer to the function that I passed it.

On stepping through the code in the VS2010 debugger however, it appears that when templating on "void (const CRect &)", that the template type is actually a class.  This then allows lamdas with captured data to be stored in the std::function.

Well, I guess I've learnt something new.